# How do I activate print button in cash journal window Adempiere?

Tags: button, printing, journal, adempiere

I want to activate print button in window "Cash Journal" Adempiere. Can someone give me an example of how to do it from creating the view in database oracle until how to register the view into adempiere print button.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The *Print* button/icon is only enabled if the Window-Tab definition in the *Application Dictionary* has a **Process** assigned.

1. Login as the **System Administrator** so you can edit the
   *Application Dictionary*
2. Create a **Print Format** for the underlying Table (C_Cash_Journal).
3. Create a new entry in the *Application Dictionary->Report & Process* and in the **Print Format** drop-down select the Print Format you created in step 2.
4. Next open the **Application Dictionary->Window, Tab & Field** menu option and select the entry for the **Cash Journal** window.
5. Select the **Tab** tab and in the **Process** drop-down select the new process you created in step 3

If you now login as **GardenAdmin** user, for example, and navigate to the *Cash Journal* window the *Print* button should now be enabled.